# About client authentication and data encryption in kafka 0.9

Tags: apache-kafka

Kafka 0.9 had announced to support client authentication and data encryption by SSL. After read the document of kafka security, it seems that if we want to use client authentication by SSL, data encryption must be used together, But using data encryption, performance will be affected. So I want to known can we only enable client authentication and disable data encryption, if it can, how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

[Using the SASL_PLAINTEXT protocol](http://docs.confluent.io/3.1.0/kafka/sasl.html), it will use Kerberos to authenticate, and then use plaintext for the rest of the protocol. I don't have personal experience using it.